# Integrating charts in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I was wondering if there is a way to integrate a bar chart and a line chart into "one single chart", where the bars are "on top of the line plot? See picture for a clearer view.

(Obviously the bar-chart is not supposed to be outside the actual plot...)

[image]

Comment: do you want the chart to look like your left image?

Comment: I don't know much about charts, but Jon Peltier sure does. You might want to check his website: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ChartIndex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Problem solved. It was actually just a matter of scaling data, and using two "line with markers" type charts. The lines in between each dot in the one showing the percentage, were then removed. Then, using a certain layout, a line connecting the two series could appear (as shown in pic).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but you could create two charts with the chart area fill transparency turned to 100%. This allows charts to be placed on top of each other, but in a way that both can be seen. Turning off any elements in the chart that you don't want (for example, duplicate axis) would enhance the presentation.

Comment: I appreciate your answer @aaronthomas, but what I would really want is to have each bar INITIATED on top of each line-dot (so in the picture, this would mean that the first bar, equal to 100%, would have its bottom or base at the first line-dot, the next bar, -100%, with its top at the second line-dot, and so on).

Basically, having the actual line-chart as the "x-axis" for the bar-chart, but the same y-axis for both...